# Make dependency property bind two way in custom control

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have custom control with following:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{TemplateBinding SampleValue}" />

public static readonly DependencyProperty SampleValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SampleValue", typeof(string), typeof(IdattFilterBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public string SampleValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(SampleValueProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(SampleValueProperty, value); }
        }
```

In a UserControl where I declare my custom control I have XAML like this:

```
<my:SampleBox SampleValue="{Binding SampleValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and ViewModel like so:

```
public string SampleValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sampleValue;
            }

            set
            {
                this.sampleValue = value;
            }
        }
```

I don't care about INotifyPropertyChanged on VM (so don't tell me about it :) )
Right now it's working as far as displaying text in text box just like I set it in VM. But when I modify this text - it doesn't get bubbled up back into VM.

What should I do? I guess I have to write some code inside custom control? Should I deal with TextBox PART and catch LostFocus? Or how does it work with TemplateBinding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TemplateBinding is inherently one way. You need to use a Binding with `Mode=TwoWay` and

`Source={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`.

Answer (score 7):

`TemplateBinding` is only `OneWay`.

If you are using Silverlight 4, you can try this,

```
{Binding SampleValue, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want `DependencyProperty.Register`  instead of `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` ?

Given your title you probably don't want to create attached property.

**edit:**

its unclear to me from code samples you provide what exactly are you trying to do.

To get two way binding you probably got 2 directions here

- Add INotifyPropertyChanged (which you don't want for some reason)
- deal with new PropertyMetadata(null)
  Instead of null supply a handler for change event there (along with
  default value if needed) and do desired things with `NewValue` there.

If possible update question so its easier to understand which control has what and who binds how. (more XAML should do)

Also notice that TextBox doesn't fire events unless it loses focus.

Comment: Yes, you correct, I didn't need Attached property. But this still doesn't solve the issue. And the issue is how do I push value entered into TextBox back to the user of this control?

Answer (score 0):

First that occurred to add `Source` binding that will show that you're binding element from context of source element.

Try to use something like:

```
<my:SampleBox SampleValue="{Binding SampleValue, Source={StaticResource someViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```